# Printing a variable in PHP does not work

Tags: php

I've got this piece of code:

```
<?php
  $userid = $me['id'];
  function showifuserexists() {
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>
  <a href="file.php?element1=aaa&userid=<?php print $userid; ?>">
</body>
</html>
<?php
} 
?>
```

For some reason I can't get the php `$userid` to show up in the html link. I've tried `echo` too. Help?

Comment: Ah, scopes. Where would we be without them.

Comment: Care to explain a bit further?

Comment: Why has this question been down-voted twice? It is not such a bad question at all.

Comment: Not sure really... I guess it's kinda nooby though no? treatment to these sorta questions around here is not nice.

Comment: @wideblade it's a pretty elementary question, but that alone would not be reason enough to downvote, though. Try working on the quality of your questions. For example, you are refering to a variable named `$me`, but the definition of the variable is nowhere to be found, making your question incomplete and harder to answer. Also, the function call to `showifuserexists()` is not seen in your code as well. These are factors that would greatly influence the quality of your question.

Comment: @Billy Moon if you check the edit history, the question you'll see that the code was poorly intendented and some words missspelled. Very little time was put into writing the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read up on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

`$userid` in your function is not the same as `$userid` outside of your function - it has a different `scope`. You could make the variable global, but that's not really good practice, especially in this context.

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve; but I guess..

```
function showifuserexists($userid=null) {
    echo '<a href="file.php?element1=aaa&userid=' . $userid . '"> ... </a>';
    // functions should *generally* return output, but for examples sake
}
```

then you would do:

```
showifuserexists($me['id']);
```

for example. But your requirements aren't really that clear.

Comment: What i need to happen, is the link will change dynamically to contain the user's id. I've tried adding global, passing the variables to the function. the script either gets stuck and the page loads blank or the userid does not show up in the link.

Comment: Where is the user's ID being obtained from? You don't really need a function for this either, if no additional processing is being done.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely a lot better off when not using an inline-created function for simple behaviour like this. Just use a simple *if-statement*:

```
<?php
    $userid = $me['id'];
    if (null !== $userid) {
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
<body>
  <a href="file.php?element1=aaa&userid=<?php print $userid; ?>">
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
?>
```

*Sidenote: the problem in your original post is that - like many others have already explained - `$userid` is defined outside the scope of your function, making it unavailable within the scope of this function.*

Answer (score 1):

`$userid` doesn't exist within `showifuserexists()`. Use [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to tell the function that the variable is found outside.

Comment: I tried adding global before the variable, yet the script just fails.

Comment: Fails how? Can you post the output of the script here?

Comment: No... It needs to go Variable definition -> Open function -> "global $var"

Comment: The script jsut gets stuck and the page is loaded blank.

Comment: "use globals"? In 2011? Seriously?

Answer (score 1):

You can't acceess the variable $userid inside the function. You can get the value by passing the variable as a function parameter.

Example code:

```
<?php
  $userid = 1;
  function showifuserexists($userid) {
?>
  <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
      <a href="file.php?element1=aaa&userid=<?php echo $userid?>" >
  </body>
  </html>
<?php
}
showifuserexists($userid);
?>
```

Hope this will help you.